# Where am I going wrong with hanging doors?

Tags: doors, finish

I am in the process of finishing my basement and I had all of the primed prehung doors installed. I removed them all to paint and change out the hardware to a different color. Ordered the exact same size hardware. Upon painting, changing out the hardware, and reinstalling the doors, I have 3 of the 6 that are rubbing in the exact same spot on the upper handle side. A lot? No, but enough to make closing the doors awfully difficult. I haven't spent a lot of time playing with the hinges and screws, was just curious as if there may be an easy solution as all 3 are rubbing in the same spot.[image]

Comment: did you unscrew the hinges? did you paint the hinge seats?

Comment: Ughh I did paint the seats not even thinking that may cause any issues. Best to sand those out and clean them up?

Comment: Show a picture of the gap on the hinge side. Show pictures of the hinges you swapped out and what you replaced them with - there are various ways that a hinge that is the "same size" can cause a door to sit in a different place

Answer (score 3):

painting will make the door slightly larger
if you paint the hinge seats it will reduce the opening crack even further, especially as paint tends pool there.

Clean the paint out of the hinge seats using a chisel, and rehang the door.